# PMP Stakeholder best level of engagement

Tags: pmp, stakeholders

In the PMBOK we have this different level of stakeholder engagement:

- Unaware
- Resistan
- Neutral
- Supportive
- Leading

What is the best level that you should have?
Because last month in a question i put Leading and he set it was wrong. This time i put Supportive on another APP and it say was Leading.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the source(s) of this question is highly suspect.  I would doubt this type of question would ever find its way to the real PMP exam because the "best" level for a stakeholder depends on the type of engagement you need from that stakeholder segment.  Therefore, there is no such thing as a "best" level of stakeholder engagement in a general context.

I would avoid those sources and find a more legitimate one to practice your questions.